# Crop image to specified size and picture location

Tags: ios, uiimage, crop, avcapturesession

I have an image that is being taken using AVCaptureSession and being returned to my view controller.

Here is a screen shot of the camera interface:

[image]

The AVCaptureSession takes the FULL SCREEN photo, and now I want to crop it down to the size of the visible window above.

The window will always be at the same location and the same size.

Height = 360 (180 non retina)px, Width = 640 (320 non retina)px, x = 0, y = 160.

How can I crop the image down to these coordinates so that the image itself is now 360 x 640?

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do something like this.  I am typing this off the top of my head, so this may not be 100% correct.

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, 640, 360, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0,-160,640,360), cgImgFromAVCaptureSession);

CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage* myCroppedImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
CGContextRelease(context);
```

Comment: I am attempting to implement this now, but what is the 4 * width supposed to be? Also, the capture manager returns a UIImage so I had to use (_bridge CGImageRef)(capturedImage). Will this make a difference?

Comment: You can get the cgImage from UIImage with the img.CGImage.  The 4 is for 4 bytes per pixel for RGBA.

Comment: Also, sorry, I meant to substitute 640 for the width, so you can just use 4*640 or set up variables for your width and height.  Also, the -160 is the y offset which could also be a variable.

Comment: This is the closest I have come! So it has cropped the image, just in an odd way. It basically turned the entire image sideways and cut it in half. I will play with the values a bit. I am also getting a warning when creating context: "Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum CGImageAlphaInfo' to different enumeration type 'CGBitmapInfo' (aka 'enum CGBitmapInfo'). Any idea what that is?

Comment: Actually, if I change the rect to (0, 0, 640, 360) it is basically taking the image and turning it sideways but it fits perfectly in the UIImageView I am sending it to